# How to return all users within nested groups?

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I'm attempting to return all users contained in a top level AD group. Let's assume the following:

App_Role (top level AD group)

This group contains both users, and other nested AD groups:
Joe | Bob | Role1 | Role2

The nested AD group Role1 contains users:
Jim | Tim

The nested AD Group Role2 contains users:
Jon | Ron

Is there a way to return all users from the top level group App_Role, while also searching through the nested groups? Ultimately, the search filter should return:
Joe | Bob | Jim | Tim | Jon | Ron

I've tried playing with

```
(&(objectClass=Group)(|(cn=*)
(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:.....)
```

but can't seem to return all users within the nested groups.

Comment: You may add flag 'Active Directory' as in LDAPv3 compliant Directory Services this would work on server side but the client has to perform it itself.

Answer (score 0):

This [filter](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Group%20Related%20Searches#section-Active+Directory+Group+Related+Searches-ResolvesAllMembersIncludingNestedSecurityGroupsRequiresAtLeastWindows2003SP2) will return all the users in the nested groups:

```
(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=App_Role,OU=Groups,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET)
```

You must use the Fully Distinguished Name of the group.

Remember, that these [LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN) type searches may fail if there are too many nested groups of the search for some other reason takes a long time to perform.

Comment: it may also be that all the group information is only available at the 'global catalogue' server.